# How do you get the navbar toggle to work before 768px?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I have been trying to figure this out all day. I am using a theme that a client wanted to use. I have replaced every mentioning of 767px and 768px with 1359px and 1360px (those are when I want the menu to collapse). I have added custom CSS. I can get the button to show up at 1359px, but it will not toggle the navigation.

Basically, the navbar toggle button does not work until I hit 767px. I do not want to know specific code I can use to fix this problem. All I want to know is where this is being set as 767px. How does the website know to change it at 767px when I have changed every mentioning of this number to 1359px. I have gone through every php file, js file, and css file on the server. I am foaming at the mouth. I think I am going to explode. I have checked EVERY solution here and elsewhere on the internet.

Is this something I need to change in javascript, in css, or in php, or in all of them?

I am using WordPress. I am looking for a general solution NOT CODE. As in, where is this being defined. What file do I need to edit in this godforsaken theme to get the menu to toggle at 1359.

Please help before my brains start oozing out of my ears.

Comment: relax, you don't need to explode :) maybe look into developer tools, and inspect the dom, see whats going on there when you click the button and it doesn't work, and when it does; without any code to look at, its really though, if not impossible,  to point out whats going on.

Comment: If you are using Twitter Bootstrap, I guess the bootstrap.css (or bootstrap.min.css) handles the width of the devices, and when a particular element shall be displayed or not.

Comment: What JS and CSS are included on your page?

Answer (score 2):

Okay well I feel like an idiot..

To anyone else having a similar issue,

CLEAR YOUR BROWSER CACHE.

Upon inspecting in developer tools I realized the site was loading an older version of my bootstrap.min.css file rather than the file I updated with the new breakpoints.

Cleared the cache and everything worked as expected.